# Find roots for piecewise function

Tags: equation-solving, piecewise

I'm trying to find the root of the function below (fun[t2_]).
FindRoot can't find it due to nlnum error, i.e. the function's output is not a number but a Condition or Plus.

How do I manage to it work?

[image]

Comment: it is hard to copy/paste code from an image. It will be better to post plain text code that one can copy. btw, you probably want to `:=` for function definition and not `=`  for your first function there.

Comment: Providing copy/pastable code will be very much appreciated. Otherwise people who want to help will have to retype all of your code, and that will limit the number of people who are willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imp` simplifies to just `r` using [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html)

```
tx[t_] = Which[t <= 180, 0.225, 180 < t <= 360, 0.2, 360 < t <= 720, 0.175, 
   t > 720, 0.150, True, 0];

imp[r_, t_] = 
 Which[r > 1, (1 - tx[t])*(r - 1) + 1, r <= 1, r, True, 1] // PiecewiseExpand

(* r *)
```

Similarly with [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
tx[t_] = Piecewise[{
    {0.225, t <= 180}, {0.2, 180 < t <= 360},
    {0.175, 360 < t <= 720}, {0.15, t > 720}}];

imp[r_, t_] = 
 Piecewise[{{(1 - tx[t])*(r - 1) + 1, r > 1}, {r, r <= 1}, {1, True}}] // 
  PiecewiseExpand

(* r *)

rbrut[Ta_, t_] = (1 + Ta)^(t/365);

rliq[Ta_, t_] = imp[rbrut[Ta, t], t]

(* (1 + Ta)^(t/365) *)

fun[t2_] = rliq[0.1836, 406] + rliq[0.0675, t2 - 406] - rliq[0.1089, t2]

(* 1.20622 + 1.0675^(1/365 (-406 + t2)) - 1.1089^(t2/365) *)

fun[500]

(* 1.07107 *)
```

To find the roots of `fun`

[image]

```
NSolve[{fun[t2] == 0, 0 < t2 < 10000}, t2][[1]]

(* {t2 -> 4008.11} *)

FindRoot[fun[t2] == 0, {t2, 1000}]

(* {t2 -> 4008.11} *)
```